# Add SQL request to Jquery accordion header

Tags: jquery, sql, accordion

i'm using the jquery accordion in order to list all email received/sent.
The header (h3+a) shows the object, the content (div) is the mail text.

HTML accordion :

```
<div id="accordion">
      <div>
            <h3><a href="#">object 1</a></h3>
            <div>mail 1 text</div>
      </div>
      <div>
            <h3><a href="#">object 2</a></h3>
            <div>mail 2 text</div>
      </div>
      <div>
            <h3><a href="#">object 3</a></h3>
            <div>mail 3 text</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Accordion script function :

```
$(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            autoHeight: false,
            header: "h3",
            navigation: true
        });
    });
```

Problem :

i would like to request my SQL database only when i clic on the header of a mail, and avoid to preload all the mails.
The other problem, much important in my case, is to mark the mail "read" or "unread". There is a column in the SQL database for this. So, the mail needs to change to "read" state when i clic on his accordion's header.

Before using accordion, i was using simple link which reloads all the page. I've no problem with PHP/SQL, but i'm not so good in javascript/jquery, or ajax...

SQL request (simplified) :

```
$sql = "SELECT mail_object, mail_text FROM table_mail ";
$req = mysql_query($sql);
```

SQL update read-state (simplified) :

```
$sql_2 = "UPDATE table_mail SET mail_read=1 ";
$req_2 = mysql_query($sql_2);
```

So, is there any way to execute this code when i clic on a header ?

After that, i'll asking you how to change header style to differentiate read/unread mail (in bold for example, or change background image/color).

Thank you.
++

Answer (score 1):

what about this

```
$("a").one('click', function(){
    $.post("url_where_php_query_db_and_update_at_the_same_time", 
     $(this).text(),
     function(xhr){
       var mailText = xhr.responseText;
       $(this).next("div").text(mailText);  //update the mail content
       //now set your mail to another class  
       $(this).addClass("read"); 
       //you need to have css to set "read" class to different style
       //e.g. a.read { font-weight: normal;}
    });
```

Comment: You might just want to change the selector to '#accordion a', in the (likely) event that you have other links on the page ;-)

Comment: Hi thx. But it doesn't work. I've also tested with simple a-link, and a basic request, but nothing happened... Seems you forget the ";" at the end, right ? maybe there is other error i dont seen ?

Comment: Yes, there should be ";" at the end. The code is just a way to convey the idea, not the tested, read-to-use one. You were just asking for an idea, weren't you? :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the post function works fine with a onclick on the accordion header:

```
<div id="accordion">
  <div>
        <h3><a onclick=$.post('update_to_read.php') href="#">object 1</a></h3>
        <div>mail 1 text</div>
  </div>
```

i'll now try to add the query for mail content.

thx.